# Focus scene2d UI actors programmatically in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d, kotlin

I am trying to implement keyboard movement in game main menu which is libGDX `Stage` with UI-Actors. I'm also trying to code this feature myself since I can't neither find anything relevant to it in the docs nor find libraries for the feature.

I have a bunch of `Button`s in the `VerticalGroup`. Using keyboard *UP* and *DOWN* keys, I want to somehow focus, highlight or hover buttons like the way that mouse hovering do. Hovewer, firing `FocusEvent` on children of the `VerticalGroup` do not change `Button` appearance.

So how do I focus these buttons or any other UI element (because there are other menus with more complex UI architecture) ?

Here is the code for the menu (Kotlin, using *ktx-scene2d* builders and *ktx-actors* event methods):

```
class MainMenuUi: Stage() {
    val root = verticalGroup {
        center()
        setFillParent(true)
        expand(true)
        space(spacing)
        fill(0.5f)
        wrap(false)

        textButton("Start")
        textButton("Settings")
        textButton("Exit")

        onKeyUp { key ->
            when(key) {
                Input.Keys.UP -> { /* ??? */ }
                Input.Keys.DOWN -> { /* ??? */ }
            }
        }
    }.also {
        addActor(it)
        keyboardFocus = it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to build something very similar but I didn't love the idea of manipulating the cursor like the other answer as it feels really hacky, though it might work.

In my case, I was also looking to be able to control everything with a controller as well. So I started with creating this concept of a `SelectableButtonGroup` which can take a Table of Buttons.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group

class SelectableButtonGroup(private val buttonGroup: Group) : SimulatesTouchOverButtons() {
    private var currentButtonIndex = 0

    fun changeSelectedButton(isUpPressed: Boolean): Boolean {
        unselectButton(buttonGroup.children[currentButtonIndex])
        val change = if (isUpPressed) {
            -1
        } else {
            1
        }
        // make sure the index wraps around
        currentButtonIndex =
            (currentButtonIndex + buttonGroup.children.size + change) % buttonGroup.children.size
        return selectButton(buttonGroup.children[currentButtonIndex])
    }

    fun clickSelected(): Boolean {
        val currentButton = buttonGroup.children[currentButtonIndex]
        return clickButton(currentButton)
    }

    fun releaseSelected(): Boolean {
        val currentButton = buttonGroup.children[currentButtonIndex]
        return releaseButton(currentButton)
    }

    fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
        return buttonGroup.children.size == 0
    }
}
```

Above uses this somewhat generic class for mimicking the mouse/touch events:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Pools

open class SimulatesTouchOverButtons {

    /**
     * Simulate button click down.
     *
     * @param button
     * @return
     */
    protected fun clickButton(button: Actor): Boolean {
        val event = Pools.obtain(
            InputEvent::class.java
        )
        event.type = InputEvent.Type.touchDown
        event.pointer = -1
        event.button = Input.Buttons.LEFT
        button.fire(event)
        val handled = event.isHandled
        Pools.free(event)
        return handled
    }

    /**
     * Simulate button click release.
     *
     * @param button
     * @return
     */
    protected fun releaseButton(button: Actor): Boolean {
        val event = Pools.obtain(
            InputEvent::class.java
        )
        event.type = InputEvent.Type.touchUp
        event.pointer = -1
        event.button = Input.Buttons.LEFT
        button.fire(event)
        val handled = event.isHandled
        Pools.free(event)
        return handled
    }

    /**
     * Simulate mousing over a button.
     *
     * @param button
     * @return
     */
    protected fun selectButton(button: Actor): Boolean {
        val event = Pools.obtain(
            InputEvent::class.java
        )
        event.type = InputEvent.Type.enter
        event.pointer = -1
        button.fire(event)
        val handled = event.isHandled
        Pools.free(event)
        return handled
    }

    /**
     * Simulate mousing off of a button.
     *
     * @param button
     * @return
     */
    protected fun unselectButton(button: Actor): Boolean {
        val event = Pools.obtain(
            InputEvent::class.java
        )
        event.type = InputEvent.Type.exit
        event.pointer = -1
        button.fire(event)
        val handled = event.isHandled
        Pools.free(event)
        return handled
    }
}
```

With `SelectableButtonGroup` we can implement a `com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor` or `com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.ControllerListener` and by sharing the same one the switching between keyboard and controller works pretty well with the shared state.

Here's the `InputProcessor`:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor

// ButtonGroupInputProcessor wraps an input processor by intercepting up and down and modifying
// a SelectableButtonGroup.
class ButtonGroupInputProcessor(
    private val inputProcessor: InputProcessor,
    private val selectableButtonGroup: SelectableButtonGroup,
) :
    InputAdapter() {

    override fun touchDragged(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer)
    }

    override fun mouseMoved(screenX: Int, screenY: Int): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.mouseMoved(screenX, screenY)
    }

    override fun keyDown(keycode: Int): Boolean {
        when (keycode) {
            Input.Keys.UP -> selectableButtonGroup.changeSelectedButton(isUpPressed = true)
            Input.Keys.DOWN -> selectableButtonGroup.changeSelectedButton(isUpPressed = false)
            Input.Keys.ENTER -> selectableButtonGroup.clickSelected()
        }

        return inputProcessor.keyDown(keycode)
    }

    override fun keyUp(keycode: Int): Boolean {
        when (keycode) {
            Input.Keys.ENTER -> selectableButtonGroup.releaseSelected()
        }


        return inputProcessor.keyUp(keycode)
    }

    override fun keyTyped(character: Char): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.keyTyped(character)
    }

    override fun touchDown(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button)
    }

    override fun touchUp(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button)
    }

    override fun touchCancelled(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.touchCancelled(screenX, screenY, pointer, button)
    }

    override fun scrolled(amountX: Float, amountY: Float): Boolean {
        return inputProcessor.scrolled(amountX, amountY)
    }
}
```

Then back to your Stage code it could look something like this:

````
...

val buttonGroup = Table()
buttonGroup.add(startButton).row()
buttonGroup.add(optionsButton).row()
buttonGroup.add(exitButton)

// Add the table to the stage
stage.addActor(buttonGroup)

// Add the listeners for the buttons
val selectableButtonGroup = SelectableButtonGroup(buttonGroup)
Controllers.addListener(ButtonGroupControllerListener(selectableButtonGroup))
// add a keyboard listener
Gdx.input.inputProcessor = ButtonGroupInputProcessor(stage, selectableButtonGroup)
```
````

Comment: I just realized today that I could have done this more simply with a com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up in the library source code how do Scene2d Actors understand that they are hovered, and it seems to work this way:

- `Button`: calling internal `ClickListener.isOver()`, which, in fact, checking *over* or *pressed* private members. Member *over* is setted when there is an *InputEvent* with **enter type** (*over* is true) or **exit type** (*over* is false) and **pointer == -1**;
- `SelectBox`: exact same way that `Button` does. Except `SelectBox` itself doesn't have `isOver` method.
- `Slider`: implementing hovering itself, using private *mouseOver* member; It is adding to itself *InputListener* that's observe *InputEvent* hovering the same way that `ClickListener` does, but change the *mouseOver* member instead of *over*.

Other UI elements either inherit from the `Button` (e.g. `CheckBox`), or don't have any hovering detection ability (and so they can't change the appearance when they are hovered).

Knowing that, I can implement `HoverEvent` that can trigger hovering in that limited list of UI elements:

```
class HoverEvent: InputEvent() {
    init {
        type = Type.enter
        pointer = -1
    }
}
```

It is change the appearance of the elements, however to un-hover such element I must manually move mouse to it and then outside of it. Or write some `UnhoverEvent`. This approach, though it seems to me the most correct one, in the end turns out to be inconvenient and in some way impractical.

---

So, as a workaround, I wrote extension function to the `Actor` that move cursor position to `Actor`'s center:

```
fun Actor.moveCursorToIt() {
    val stageCoords = localToStageCoordinates(Vector2())
    val screenCoords = stage.stageToScreenCoordinates(stageCoords)
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(
            (screenCoords.x + width / 2).toInt(),
            (screenCoords.y - height / 2).toInt()
    )
}
```